# Point x cor calculate in given direction

Tags: math, geometry

Given my position as **(x, y)**. I wish to calculate the xcor (the x coordinate) for a point whose ycor (the y coordinate)I know. The direction is **theta** (an angle with the vertical).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xcor = x0 + t * Sin(Theta)
ycor = y0 + t * Cos(Theta)
```

find t from 2nd equation and use it in 1st equation

(note Cos/Sin exchange, because you mentioned theta as an angle with the **vertical**